# show time and date from DB timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I am trying to print a date and time stored in a DB.

Here is my code

```
 print date("d-m-y H:i",strtotime($created));
```

This shows the date as `01-01-70 01:00` however the date in the DB is `2013-10-04 14:18:17`

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `var_dump($created);` output?

Comment: [Your code should work](http://codepad.org/o9D7TDKw). Your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: This outputs `01-01-70 01:00`

Comment: Ah, there's your problem. Paste the full code, it seems you're not getting the value from the DB properly.

Comment: So what do i need to fix the issue?

Comment: Make sure that `$created` contains what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sure about that ? i test it and got worked :

```
date("d-m-y H:i",strtotime('2013-10-04 14:18:17')); // output : 04-10-13 14:18
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in the database in the format yyyy-mm-dd and the when you retrieve it from the database use

$date = the date data from the database;

```
$date = date_parse($date);
echo $date['day'].'-'.$date['month'].'-'.$date['year'];
```

[php parse_date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)

You can even take the date in dd-mm-yyyy then just change to the database format before inserting.

example:

```
$date = date($_POST['year'].'-'. $_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day']);
```